# Website forwarding without revealing the forwarding address on browser

Tags: html, web-hosting

I am a newbie to building websites. I have a google domain 
www.example.com, 
and a location: 
other.com/myLocation, which contains my actual web page.

Currently, I have enabled website forwarding in google domains, which means, if I enter www.example.com, I get redirected to other.com/myLocation

Is there any way to make it so that I do not get other.com/myLocation, but www.example.com only on my browser?

Comment: For what purpose?  If you just want users to see the domain in the address bar then I suppose you could have a full-page iframe to your real website.  You'd want to be careful to ensure off-site links open in the full frame though, otherwise that could annoy users.

Answer (score 0):

You could use URL masking, which essentially bakes the destination page inside of an iFrame. Otherwise, depending on the setup, I'd recommend making changes at the DNS level.